# Querying a tenants Azure AD from a multi-tenant Application

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have a multi-tenant Saas application providing sign in using our username/pwd authentication system and using Azure AD (OAuth 2.0 flows). When a user signs in using Azure AD, we can get the user's profile using https://graph.windows.net/{tenantid}/me. We want however to get more information using the memberOf or getMemberGroups operations to retrieve the user's groups in the tenants directory, to map specific groups from the tenant to an organizational structure in our application. However these operations always fail with a Forbidden statuscode. Are we missing required permissions or is it just not possible to query for the groups and roles of another tenant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you ever get answer to your question?  I need help on this area as well. Need to get memberOf or identify user's role

Comment: @user332951. We finally got it working adding an on boarding page for administrators of the tenant to give consent to query the additional information like groups. See the Azure AD examples on [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally possible, but today requires that you request the "Read Directory" permission.  This permission does require and admin of the tenant to consent.  We are looking at adding some additional fine grained permissions for Graph API that will allow users to consent (to get group membership information).

Another option for you is to configure your application to request group membership claims (which should appear in any user or JWT token).  You can do this by going to the azure management portal and getting to your app's config page.  From there download the application manifest file and update the groupMembershipClaims property. You can see most of the properties in the application manifest described here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151677.aspx.  Once updated, you can upload this app manifest file, and this will configure your application accordingly.  Once done, AAD will issue group membership claims in the token.  Dushyant has written a nice blog about authorizing access to a web app, using group membership claims or app roles.  You can find it via Alex Simons blog post here:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx

HTHs

Comment: Alex Simon's article has moved to https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/